# Enumerating COM collections using foreach

Tags: c#, .net, com, vsto

Many people are recommending ([link](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SPA-703)) enumerating COM collections using a `foreach` is a bad idea and always use normal `for` loop to iterate. I have an Outlook Addin which uses `foreach` to iterate over `Items` collection and fails with `0x9AC70005` exception for some users. So I am wondering is `foreach` causing any issues?

Can some one help to understand why `foreach` is a bad idea to iterate COM collections?

Comment: The exception 0x9AC70005's cause is win32 error 5 E_ACCESSDENIED. This error has nothing to do with how collection is iterated. Check security permissions on your clients machines.

Comment: thanks. Can you tell me how you got the `E_ACCESSDENIED`?

Comment: That's not a proper COM error code.  You need to get more details about the failure.  Using foreach on COM enumerators is fine, it was what they were made to do.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks. Is there a way to get the proper COM error code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT